# List of references to items in a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, pointers

Is there a way, in python, for me to create a list where each element is a reference to an element in a dictionary? This way, I can maintain a sorted list, while also being able to change the value by indexing into the dictionary.

```
d = {
  'price_one': 12,
  'price_two': 13,
  'price_three': 5
}

sorted_list = [ptr_to_price_three, ptr_to_price_one, ptr_to_price_two]
print(sorted_list) # [5, 12, 13]

d['price_one'] = 1

sorted_list.sort() # [ptr_to_price_one, ptr_to_price_three, ptr_to_price_two]
print(sorted_list) # [1, 5, 13]
```

Comment: Not sure what the actual use case is here, but would it be solved by `OrderedDict`? https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict

Comment: @JacobIRR Interesting. It looks like this could work for me. If I were to change a value in the dictionary, would the order also change?

Comment: OrderedDict (and normal dict on python 3.7+ / ipython 3.6+) are insert ordered - the only way to keep them ordered is to create them a-new: `d =dict(d.items())` after changing something - which is not really good. Why do you need this and whatfor - how big is the dict? Why not create a `def get_ordered_items(d): return sorted(d.values())` funciton?

Comment: @PatrickArtner It seems likes I need to resort after every modification anyway so this may be the best option

Comment: Are you trying to efficiently maintain a sorted container? Because then you should just use [sorted containers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga The goal is to maintain a sorted container where elements can be modified by key (and that key lookup is O(logn) or faster)

Comment: @bpgeck you should *really* look at that library then. I suspect it will be much faster than anything you roll out on your own. They have a `SortedDict` performance that has proven quite fast, especially given that it beats out various C++ library implementations using the usual suspects (e.g. red-black trees) and it is *written in pure python*. [Check out the performance comparisons](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/performance.html#sorted-dict). Note, for `__getitem__` it outperforms all those fancy C/C++ libraries!

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned Python in general. You could use a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

d = {
  'price_one': 12,
  'price_two': 13,
  'price_three': 5
}

df = pd.DataFrame(list(d.values()), columns=['val'], index=d.keys())
df.loc['price_one'] = 1
df.sort_values(['val'])
```

Outputs:

[image]

Comment: Pulling in `pandas` (and incredibly heavyweight framework) for this seems a bit much. It's fine if you're using `pandas` anyway, but I wouldn't use it as a go-to solution in general.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
d = {
    'price_one': 12,
    'price_two': 13,
    'price_three': 5
}

def get_sorted(d):
    sorted_list = sorted(list(d.values()))
    return tuple(zip(sorted_list, d[key] for key in sorted_list))
# end get_sorted

print(get_sorted(d))

d['price_one'] = 1

print(get_sorted(d))
```

Note that you would have to call `get_sorted(d)` each time...

Also, it returns a tuple of pairs (key, value) sorted with their keys. If you wanted to access say the 3rd value, do `get_sorted(d)[2][1]`. The `2` for the third pair, the `1` for the value.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this won't work. When this line is executed `d['price_one'] = 1`, the value will not change in the list

Comment: I've changed it so it's a function instead. It might not be pretty but it works.

Comment: No problem. If it works, you can help other programmers like you get this answer when they see this question by pressing the checkmark to mark it as a correct answer. Keep up the great work :D

Answer (score 0):

The dictionary keys are references to particular entries in a dictionary.

A function to generate a list of dictionary keys in the order of the dictionary entry values is:

```
def sorted_keys(d):
    return sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda k: d[k])
```

so to access the smallest price in your example:

```
ks = sorted_keys(d)
smallest = d[ ks[0] ]
```

The problem is that you have to recalculate your ordering on any insert, change or delete of the dictionary. These would be hard to intercept so better to keep control and recalculate the ordering just when you want to use it.

You could bury all this in a `class SortedDict(dict)` that overrides the get function of a dictionary.